# Mix_OpenAudio Closes Program Without Creating Window

Tags: c++, makefile, sdl-2, sdl-mixer

I want to create a simple program that lets me move around a little sprite with some music.

I'm able to bring up a window, my next step is getting some music. I have everything setup properly as when I build my main.exe with make it builds perfectly. I've narrowed the issue down to the first instance when the mixer is used in the line `Mix_OpenAudio(48000, AUDIO_S16SYS, 2, 1024`.

I'm not sure why it's not working, but when this line is included, the program simply doesn't open the window and ends the program. On the contrary, when the line isn't included, then the window opens just fine. I've provided a screencap to further illustrate:

[image: Screencap]

Here is my main.cpp code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDl2/SDL_mixer.h>

//Define window size
const int WIDTH = 800;
const int HEIGHT = 600;

bool init();
void closeWindow();

SDL_Window *window = NULL;

bool init() {


    window = SDL_CreateWindow("test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);
    if (NULL == window) {
        std::cout << "Could not create window: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }

}

void closeWindow() {

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return;

}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    /* Initialize the SDL library */
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't initialize SDL: %s\n",SDL_GetError());
        exit(2);
    }
    /* Opens the audio device */
    if (Mix_OpenAudio(48000, AUDIO_S16SYS, 2, 1024) < 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Warning: Couldn't set 48000Hz 16-bit audio\n- Reason: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }

    init();

    SDL_Event windowEvent;
    while(true) {
        if(SDL_PollEvent(&windowEvent)) {
            if (SDL_QUIT == windowEvent.type) {
                break;
            }
        }

        
        

    }

    closeWindow();
    Mix_CloseAudio();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure why you felt it was necessary to include the image. It provides zero value to the question. Images should be used only when demonstrating an issue that cannot be shown any other way, and console text can be copied and pasted directly, and even if you pasted the text in, it still adds nothing to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I had been working at this for a while and was tired

Comment: SDL version?  SDL_mixer version?  Using SDL/SDL_mixer binaries from github or are they self-built?